# How to create a new list based on an old one in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the list in my controller:

```
$scope.newsLists = [
   { newsName: list1, newsStatus: isOpen },
   { newsName: list2, newsStatus: isOpen },
   { newsName: list3, newsStatus: isOpen },
   { newsName: list4, newsStatus: isClosed }
];
```

then I'd like to create another list based on this `$scope.newsList`.

such as:

```
$scope.valueNewsLists = $scope.newsLists(list.newsStatus == isOpen);
```

But I don't know how to create the `$scope.valueNewsLists` in a correct way.

I do need this list because I have to write a function for pages.

If somebody have a explication for this problem, I would be very appreciated !

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Comment: $scope.valueNewsLists = $scope.newsLists.filter(function(news){return news.newsStatus === 'isOpen'}) see this [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @aarosil you have basically copied my answer into your comment

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak sorry mate, didn't notice it

Answer (score 1):

You can filter existing array with built in Javascript [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var isOpen = function(element) {
    return element.newsStatus == isOpen
}
$scope.valueNewsLists = $scope.newsLists.filter(isOpen);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter on template in order to get the result you wanted.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in newsList| filter:{newsStatus:'isOpen'}">
    <input ng-model="list.newsName" />
</div>
```